# Taking cart id and putting into order table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, model-associations

i have model **order.rb** :

`class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :cart 
end`

and model **cart.rb** :

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    include SecurelyPermalinkable
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :order

end
```

How can i take cart_id and put it in column of order table ?

Thanks

Michael

Comment: As per the given associations you wont have `cart_id` in your `order` table.You will be having `order_id` in your `cart` table.You are just confused.You have to read these Guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association

Answer (score 1):

As I said,you should be doing like that way,You will be having `order_id` in your `cart` table because your associations are set like that

if you really want `cart_id` in your `order` table then you have to change your associations.

**Order model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :cart 
end
```

**Cart model**

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
        include SecurelyPermalinkable
        belongs_to :user
        has_one :order

    end
```